# Xamarin.Forms: Performance differences in using DynamicResource over StaticResource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, dynamicresource

I've seen a few questions asked around the performance difference in using DynamicResource over StaticResource but it's mainly been around WPF and not Xamarin.Forms mobile apps.

The context of my question is around a specific use-case I've got:

I have an application that only uses StaticResources at the moment but need the ability to have a 'flavour' of the app  (determined by an internal build time flag) that is able to change the style/theme at runtime -- the variables to be controlled via an API upon app initialisation.

So I'm currently facing the situation where I would need to change all StaticResource references in the XAML layouts to use DynamicResource. **What are the performance implications of this?**

Alternatively, would it be possible to write my own markup extension to return if it should use DynamicResource or a StaticResource depending on the internal 'flavour' flag that is currently set? So that way I don't need to ship code that references dynamic resources if the flavour does not require it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

According to offical document [Dynamic Styles in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic):

> The DynamicResource markup extension is similar to the StaticResource
> markup extension in that both use a dictionary key to fetch a value
> from a ResourceDictionary. However, while the StaticResource performs
> a single dictionary lookup, the DynamicResource maintains a link to
> the dictionary key. Therefore, if the dictionary entry associated with
> the key is replaced, the change is applied to the visual element. This
> enables runtime style changes to be made in an application.

Edit:
The dynamicResources will override the staticresources if they both exist.
I did a test about change staticresources into dynamic.

**Xmal:**

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes"
                    Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor"
                    Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" x:Name="MyLabel"/>
            <Button Clicked="OnButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**codebehind:**

```
public Page1(bool IsDynamic)
    {
        var dynamicstyle = new Style(typeof(Label)) {
            Setters = { new Setter { Property=Label.FontProperty,
            Value="Bold"},
            new Setter{
            Property=Label.TextColorProperty,
            Value="Blue"} }
        };
        InitializeComponent();
        if (IsDynamic)
        { MyLabel.Style = dynamicstyle; }
    }
    private void OnButton_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(true));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the documentation and that does not really answer my question

Comment: I create a sample page, you can check

Comment: I agree, nothing in this answer addresses the performance concerns.